# onPageScrolled method returns null after changing to lastest Support-v4 library

Tags: android

i have a strange problem here, i have a dialog fragment and this method is inside it :

```
 @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        currentPosition = position;
        currentPositionOffset = positionOffset;

        scrollToChild(position, (int) (positionOffset *  
 tabsContainer.getChildAt(position).getWidth()));

        invalidate();

        if (delegatePageListener != null) {
            delegatePageListener.onPageScrolled(position, 
 positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
        }
    }
```

when i use an older version of support-v4.jar it works fine, but when i use latest version of it, this method:

```
scrollToChild(position, (int) (positionOffset *  
tabsContainer.getChildAt(position).getWidth()));
```

returns this error:

```
 06-19 11:56:23.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1024): java.lang.NullPointerException
 06-19 11:56:23.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):    at         
 com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip$PageListener.onPageScrolled
(PagerSlidingTabStrip.java:361)
 06-19 11:56:23.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):    at 
 android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onPageScrolled(ViewPager.java:1712)
 06-19 11:56:23.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):    at 
 android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.pageScrolled(ViewPager.java:1633)
 06-19 11:56:23.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):    at 
 android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:581)
 06-19 11:56:23.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):    at  
 android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1600)
```

do you understand what is wrong?

Comment: my guess is position is null that time, but what can i do about that and why is this happening !

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpul.

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/issues/69

I just came up with the same problem, after a little testing, I confirmed the reason is there are no items to show within `PagerSlidingTabStrip`.

If you're sure that you have data that should be displayed, on the `PagerSlidingTabStrip`, maybe you've forgotten to call `PagerSlidingTabStrip.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Hope this helps you!